# How to add an item from the Activity in ListFragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

How to add an item from the Activity in ListFragment?

```
public class LoadObjects extends ListFragment 
{

    String data[] = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**How can I upload the menu items of the Activity in this FragmentList? Please give an example or a link.**

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347927/listfragment-how-do-i-add-a-menu

Comment: When you say menu items do you mean the MenuItem's from the applications menu? If so why are you trying to put them in a ListFragment?

Comment: you little misunderstood. I have a server, he load data in MyActivity. How do downloaded data  Add in ListFragment? ( string )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your adapter as an instance variable so you can reference it from anywhere. Then you can add items to it from your activity.

```
public class LoadObjects extends ListFragment 
{

    String data[] = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
    public ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                data);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Then to update the ListFragment's ListView from your activity do this:

```
FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
LoadObjects frag = (LoadObjects) fManager.findFragmentByTag("listFragment");
if (frag != null) {
    frag.mAdapter.addAll(youNewData);
}
```

Of course note that when creating the LoadObjects fragment you need to set a tag for it like this:

```
LoadObjects frag = new LoadObjects();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, frag, "listFragment");
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                {
                    LoadObjects frag = new LoadObjects();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.layout.load_objects, frag, "listFragment");
                    transaction.commit();
                    return frag;
                }
                case 1:
                    return new AddObject();
            }

        }

Comment: when run, takes off(( help please

Comment: Activity uses SectionsPagerAdapter